# Importing data from Excel into Access using DAO and WHERE clause

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import, import-from-excel

I need to import certain information from an Excel file into an Access DB and in order to do this, I am using DAO.

The user gets the excel source file from a system, he does not need to directly interact with it.  This source file has 10 columns and I would need to retrieve only certain records from it.

I am using this to retrieve all the records:

```
Set destinationFile = CurrentDb
Set dbtmp = OpenDatabase(sourceFile, False, True, "Excel 8.0;")
DoEvents
Set rs = dbtmp.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [EEX_Avail_Cap_ALL_DEU_D1_S_Y1$A1:J65536]")
```

My problem comes when I want to retrieve only certain records using a WHERE clause.  The name of the field where I want to apply the clause is 'Date (UCT)' (remember that the user gets this source file from another system) and I can not get the WHERE clause to work on it.  If I apply the WHERE clause on another field, whose name does not have ( ) or spaces, then it works.  Example:

```
Set rs = dbtmp.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [EEX_Avail_Cap_ALL_DEU_D1_S_Y1$A1:J65536] WHERE Other = 12925")
```

The previous instruction will retrieve only the number of records where the field Other has the value 12925.

Could anyone please tell me how can I achieve the same result but with a field name that has spaces and parenthesis i.e. 'Date (UCT)' ?

Thank you very much.

Octavio

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the field name in square brackets:

`SELECT * FROM [EEX_Avail_Cap_ALL_DEU_D1_S_Y1$A1:J65536] WHERE [Date (UCT)] = 12925`

or if it's a date we are looking for:

`SELECT * FROM [EEX_Avail_Cap_ALL_DEU_D1_S_Y1$A1:J65536] WHERE [Date (UCT)] = #02/14/13#;`

To use date literal you must enclose it in # characters and write the date in MM/DD/YY format regardless of any regional settings on your machine

Comment: Hi barrowc, I've tried what you suggest but I don't get any record.  Also, the field [Date (UCT)] is supposed to hold dates.  I did a test changing all the values on that field to numbers but still got an empty rs.  Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The `= 12925` part came straight from the question. I've amended my answer to show a date comparison